# Jquery mouseover and mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one problem about mouseover and mouseleave function.

In this **[DEMO](http://www.ecowebtr.com/Untitled/index.php)** page you can see there is a picture. When you hover over muse then you can see the hovercard. The hovercard inside have click to follow link. But you can not click that link because when you mouseleave on that link the hovercard to be closed. How can I solve this problem. Is anyone can help me ?

The Jquery code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
function showProfileTooltip(e, id){ 
e.append($('.p-tooltip').css({ 
'top':'20', 
'left':'80' 
}).show()); 
//send id & get info from go_card.php 
$.ajax({
    url: 'go_card.php?uid='+id,
    beforeSend: function(){
    $('.p-tooltip').html('Yükleniyor..');
},
success: function(html){ 
$('.p-tooltip').html(html); 
} 
}); 
} 

function hideProfileTooltip(){ 
$('.p-tooltip').hide(); 
} 

$('.summary a').mouseover(function(e){ 
var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
showProfileTooltip($(this), id); 
}); 

$('.summary').mouseleave(function(){ 
hideProfileTooltip(); 
});
});
```

and HTML code:

```
<div class="paylasilan-alani">
     <div class="paylasan-profil-fotosu profile">
        <div class="summary" id="summary1" data-id="7"><a href="#" class="" data-id="7"><img src="http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Frozen-Movie-poster-payoff-Wallpaper-HD1.jpg" width="64" height="64"/></a></div>
         </div>
    <div class="paylasilan">Some text here.</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's rather hard to edit your script. Try placing the functionality you want in a jsfiddle and you'll probably have better chances of getting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the `.mouseover()` function which is triggering the ajax call over and over.

per the documentation for [.mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/):

`This event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For instance, when the mouse pointer moves over the Inner element in this example, a mouseover event will be sent to that, then trickle up to Outer. This can trigger our bound mouseover handler at inopportune times. See the discussion for .mouseenter() for a useful alternative.`

instead switch to `.hover()`. You can use a callback to handle the `mouseleave()` functionality too:

```
$('.summary a').hover(function(e){ 
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
   showProfileTooltip($(this), id); 
}, function(){
   hideProfileTooltip(); 
});
```

Also the plugin you are using which is adding inline styles to `.summary` and the class `scroll-to-fixed-fixed` is setting `.summary` to `z-index:0`. The `z-index` property is inherited by it's children and this is causing your pop up to sit behind other elements. I would either look through the plugin's JS file and remove this or override it in your CSS by adding:

```
.summary{
   z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/qucedu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
function hideProfileTooltip(){ 
  $('.p-tooltip').hide(); 
} 

$('.summary a').mouseover(function(e){ 
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
  showProfileTooltip($(this), id); 
}); 

$('.summary').mouseleave(function(){ 
  hideProfileTooltip(); 
});
```

This is your issue code. To achieve your purpose. The key is the`.p-tooltip` doesn't disapper when trigger the function `ummary.mouseleave` if your cursor move to the `.p-tooltip`,but when your cursor move to other place. The `.p-tooltip` should be disappear.

So I create a [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/qucedu/1/edit?html,css,js,output) to simulate your issue. The jsbin simply simulates your problem. It's just a way with a HTML structure to fixed your issue. I believe there is another way to resolve it. But use this structure is a brief way to make it. So, I advise you should repaint your HTML, **specially pay more attention the parent & child relation.**

That's all.

Comment: Please only use back-ticks, not bold, to indicate inline code.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the mouseleave function inside the mouse enter function. This way, after focusing on the element, it hides if the user leaves the element.